# WordPress Security and Possible Hacking

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to WordPress and I've just found an email saying I have a new user, and sure as chips there was a new subscriber, even though I had not been asked to allow it.

Is this normal or was my site hacked?

Comment: May want to ask this at http://security.stackexchange.com/ instead. StackOverFlow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be normal. Is your website live? And you have any 'subscribe now' option? It seems someone came to your website and subscribed to it!

It's not hacked for sure!

Comment: I admire your confidence that the web site isn't hacked.  Granted, a subscriber being added doesn't automatically indicate a hacked site, but the site could be hacked despite the subscriber, or it might be that the subscriber subscribed in order to hack.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal. Anyone can register on your WordPress site. But if you don't want any subscribers, then you could disable Sign up function. And for security, you should install plugins like jetpack.